# Calcular áreas y perímetros de Circulo, Rectángulo, Cuadrado o Triángulo

Tags: java

Cálculo de Áreas Y Perímetros

Menú:

1. Circulo
2. Rectángulo
3. Cuadrado
4. Triangulo
5. Salir

Mensaje ("Calculo de Área y Perímetros")

Áreas: Reciban y regresen resultados para ser mostrados

Perímetros: No regresan nada pero reciben datos

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mensaje();
        for (;;){
            String op=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " Elige una opcion \n" +
                        "1.- circulo \n" +
                        "2.- rectangulo \n" +
                        "3.- cuadrado \n" +
                        "4.- triangulo \n" +
                        "5.- salir \n");
            int opci=0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo? Si es así ponlo porque realmente lo que ahí muestras son simplemente las opciones, y seguramente que ese código te lo dieron junto con el enunciado de las tareas del cole...

Comment: Para que podamos ayudarte tienes que poner tu código y decirnos en que falla o donde te has quedado pero como dice @JoseD.Jurado no muestras nada, ese código parece el enunciado de un ejercicio que te han mandado y aquí no se resuelven ejercicios de clase.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes realizarlo mediante funciones de static void las cuales peden recibir parametros y no regresan ningun valor y para la seleccion puedes utilizar un switch para las figuras que te estan pidiendo